# How do I create a new instance of thread multiple times in same program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am a newbie please forgive me if I am not clear with what I want. I have a java app which inserts into 2 mysql tables upon clicking submit, one is the on the local machine and other on the web server . The problem is I have created two Threads , one for each . It works fine the first time the app is launched and started , but when the app is running and i try to insert again by clicking submit , it does not do anything . Again when I restart the app it works fine for the first time . my question is how do I stop the thread or end and start a new instance of it , in the same instance of my app.

Am sorry if am not clear .

heres the code,

```
  final int m = MSfuntion.getmemomoc();

 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
 public void run()
 { 
while(runt1){

try{
        for(int i=0;i<=jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Object slno= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
                Object item2=  jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2);
                Object size2= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3);

                String it = slno.toString();
                String si = item2.toString();
                int qt = Integer.parseInt(size2.toString());

                MSfuntion.saledetails(m,it, si, qt);
                //MSfuntion.saledetailsweb(m,it, si, qt);
                sc=0;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    runt1=false;

   }
  }

});
 Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

 public void run()
{ 
while(runt2){

 try{
        for(int i=0;i<=jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Object slno= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
                Object item2=  jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2);
                Object size2= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3);

                String it = slno.toString();
                String si = item2.toString();
                int qt = Integer.parseInt(size2.toString());

                //MSfuntion.saledetails(m,it, si, qt);
                MSfuntion.saledetailsweb(m,it, si, qt);
                sc=0;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    runt2=false;
       }
     t1.start();
     t2.start()
```

Comment: The code you have shown will create 2 threads, which will run until the variables `runt*n*` are false (though that logic is redundant) at which point the theads will terminate.  It not clear from your code how the `runt*n*` variables are set, though obviously it is outside of the `Runnable`s, which may cause unpredictable results if this code is triggered repeatedly.  Please show all the code or indicate how this block of code is invoked.

Comment: This blocks code is invoked upon clicking jbutton , using ActionListener

Comment: I have declared it as ," private volatile boolean runt1= true;
    private volatile boolean runt2= true; " at the starting of the class. Sorry cannot post the entire class as it is huge.

Comment: The `run*n*` variables and the loop are not needed at all.

Comment: OK so I remove them . now what?

Comment: Providing the `ActionListener` is being invoked there's no reason I can see why new threads wouldn't be created.  Are you sure this code is being called a with the second button click?

Comment: @CleanX : Please have a look at this example, [StartStopPauseThread.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5021rcrhw3ewngd/StartStopPauseThread.java), hopefully it might can give you the idea, how to exactly do that thingy. I will add some text to it also, to explain a bit better shortly, just need some time for that :(

Comment: CleanX Could you please add the whole class so that we can see if there's anything else that could be complicating things?

Comment: @NickHolt could it be because  I don't commit the write or release the database connection after I write the data into both tables.?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what's in `MSfuntion`, but in general you should always call close on a `java.sql.Connection` when you're finished with it.  `java.sql.Connection` normally has auto commit set to `true` but if this isn't the case then you should commit the transaction after the writes.  It is however unlikely that either of these problems would prevent you being able to create threads.

Comment: @NickHolt I have added the function from MSfuntion  and the ActionListener, please Help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a threading issue to me. It sounds like you don't commit the write or release the database connection after you write the data into both tables. Depending on how you write the data to the database, it can happen that it works with one Thread, but not if you do it from multiple threads. When you run it the first time, the first thread locks the database and the Thread that is created for the second write, can't write data because the first thread didn't release the lock.

One other thing, instead of spawning two threads every time someone clicks the button, it would be much better to use an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: I have added the db function and the ActionListener, please Help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the while loops and I don't think that you need them. Nevertheless, the second while uses runt1 as break condition. Probably that's not on purpose

Comment: Sorry typing error , have corrected it . But that doesnt solve my query though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this fixes your problem. This first time you run the program both runt1 and runt2 are probably set to true. After running it the first time they will have been set to false, thus causing the while block to be skipped.

```
final int m = MSfuntion.getmemomoc();

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){ 
        runt1 = true;
        while(runt1){

            try{
                // same as in your code before
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runt1=false;

        }
    }

});
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run(){ 
        runt2=true;
        while(runt2){

            try{
                // your normal code here
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runt2=false;
        }
    }
};
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: The `run*n*` and the loop provides no benefit whatsoever, the code will behave the same and be more readable if they were removed.

Answer (score 1):

here is the db layer of my app.

```
   public static void saledetails(int mem, String item2,String size2,int qty2)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(GUIbuilding.con,GUIbuilding.usr,GUIbuilding.pass);                  

            String sql = "INSERT INTO salesdetails VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setInt(1, mem);  
            ps.setString(2, item2);
    ps.setString(3, size2);
    ps.setInt(4, qty2);                

            ps.executeUpdate();

            String sql2 = "update stock set qty = qty - ? where item= ? && size = ?";                
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

            ps1.setInt(1, qty2);  
            ps1.setString(2, item2);
    ps1.setString(3, size2);

            ps1.executeUpdate();

       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

     //-------------- sales details------------------------

    public static void saledetailsweb(int mem, String item2,String size2,int qty2)
    {
        try
        {   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,    GUIbuilding.conweb+"\n"+GUIbuilding.usrweb+"\n"+GUIbuilding.passweb);
            Connection con =      DriverManager.getConnection(GUIbuilding.conweb,GUIbuilding.usrweb,GUIbuilding.passweb);                  



            String sql2 = "update stock set qty = qty - ? where item= ? && size = ?";                
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

            ps1.setInt(1, qty2);  
            ps1.setString(2, item2);
    ps1.setString(3, size2);

            ps1.executeUpdate();

       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    //---------------------purchase details----------------------------------------------
     public static void purdetails(int mem, String item2,String size2,int qty2)
    {
        try
        {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(GUIbuilding.con,GUIbuilding.usr,GUIbuilding.pass);                  

            String sql = "INSERT INTO purdetails VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setInt(1, mem);  
            ps.setString(2, item2);
    ps.setString(3, size2);
    ps.setInt(4, qty2);                

            ps.executeUpdate();

            String sql2 = "update stock set qty = qty + ? where item= ? && size = ?";                
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);

            ps1.setInt(1, qty2);  
            ps1.setString(2, item2);
    ps1.setString(3, size2);

            ps1.executeUpdate();

       }
       catch(SQLException e)
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

And here is the entire action listener.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //sales confirm
       boolean runt1= true;
       boolean runt2= true;
    String cust = jTextField1.getText();
    String Is = jTextField2.getText();
    //jTextField3.getText();
    int sales_order_total_quantity =0;

    if(cust.equalsIgnoreCase("") || Is.equalsIgnoreCase("") ||  jTable2.getRowCount()==0)
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter all the required Feilds \n in order to update Sales memo");         
    }
    else
    {                      
    jTextField1.setText("");
    jTextField2.setText("");



    try{ 
        if(jTable2.getRowCount()==0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter the Items in the sales memo");
        }
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Object slno= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
                Object item2=  jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2);
                Object size2= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3);

                String it = slno.toString();
                String si = item2.toString();
                int qt = Integer.parseInt(size2.toString());
                sales_order_total_quantity += qt; 

               // MSfuntion.saledetails(m,it, si, qt);
                sc=0;
            }
        }

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
  //e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
  {

 MSfuntion.sales(cust, Is,sales_order_total_quantity);
 final int m = MSfuntion.getmemomoc();
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, m);
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

 public void run()
{   
   try{ boolean runt1= true;
    while(runt1){

    try{
        for(int i=0;i<=jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Object slno= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
                Object item2=  jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2);
                Object size2= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3);

                String it = slno.toString();
                String si = item2.toString();
                int qt = Integer.parseInt(size2.toString());
               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread is still alive bro");
                MSfuntion.saledetails(m,it, si, qt);
                //MSfuntion.saledetailsweb(m,it, si, qt);
                sc=0;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    runt1=false;

  }
  }     catch(Exception e1){e1.printStackTrace();}}

});
 Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){

 public void run()
  { boolean runt2= true;
 while(runt2){


 try{
        for(int i=0;i<=jTable2.getRowCount();i++)
            {
                Object slno= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1);
                Object item2=  jTable2.getValueAt(i, 2);
                Object size2= jTable2.getValueAt(i, 3);

                String it = slno.toString();
                String si = item2.toString();
                int qt = Integer.parseInt(size2.toString());
               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thread is still alive bro");
                //MSfuntion.saledetails(m,it, si, qt);
                MSfuntion.saledetailsweb(m,it, si, qt);
                sc=0;
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    runt2=false;



}
}

});

 t1.start();
 t2.start();


    //---------------clear table sales memo---------------------
        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] 
        {

        },
        new String [] 
        {
             "Sl no", "Item", "Size", "Quantity"
        }
        ) 
        {
        Class[] types = new Class [] 
        {
             java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Integer.class
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) 
        {
        return types [columnIndex];
       }
        });
        //-----------clear table low stock----------------------
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] 
        {

        },
        new String [] 
        {
             "Item","Size","Quantity"
        }
        ) 
        {
        Class[] types = new Class [] 
        {
             java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Integer.class
        };

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) 
        {
        return types [columnIndex];
       }
        });
        //--------------------clear table recent sales----------------------------
         jTable4.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
            "Customer", "Issuer", "Date", "Memo No", "Quantity"
        }
    ));  
         MSfuntion.tablepop_sr_recent(jTable4);
         MSfuntion.tablepop_low(jTable1);

  }}
  //end of listener

}
```